# How do I extend RouterOutlet when using the new router in RC.1

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I can't seem to extend RouterOutlet when using the new router in RC.1

Example:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';


@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})

export class RouterOutletDirective extends RouterOutlet {

}
```

The error:

> @angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'RouterOutlet'.

Am i doing something wrong or is this broke with the new router in RC.1?

---

### Updated:

```
import { Directive, Attribute, ViewContainerRef, DynamicComponentLoader } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Routes, RouterOutletMap } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet';


@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})
export class RouterOutletDirective extends RouterOutlet {

  constructor(parentOutletMap: RouterOutletMap, _location: ViewContainerRef, name: string) {
    super(parentOutletMap, _location, name);
    console.log( parentOutletMap );
  }


  activate() {
    console.log('Activate');
  }
}
```

So it's now running but the RouterOutlet is underlined in red with type "any" is not a constructor function type and also the activate part doesn't work. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RouterOutlet` and `RouterLink` are not exported from `@angular/router`. This was fixed already recently and I'd expect this fix to be included in RC.2.

You can import them from the private path (`src/...`) as a workaround until the new version is published.

**Hint**

That said, there is again a new router work in progress. If you currently working on migrating from the beta router or `@angular/router-derprecated` to `@angular/router` it's probably better to postpone until the new new router is out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've updated my question with what you mentioned and the problem that i now have.

Comment: I don't know about the constructor error but AFAIK you need a different selector from the original if you provide `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` otherwise this causes a conflict.

Answer (score 3):

Here is working code with version RC 1

```
import { Directive, Attribute, ViewContainerRef, DynamicComponentLoader } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Routes, RouterOutletMap } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet';

@Directive({
    selector: 'router-outlet'
})
export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {

    constructor(parentOutletMap: RouterOutletMap, _location: ViewContainerRef, name: string){
        super(parentOutletMap, _location, name);

    }
    //activate() {} //EXPIRED
    unload(): void { }
    loadedComponent: Object
    isLoaded: boolean
    load(factory, providers, outletMap: RouterOutletMap): any {
        super.load(factory, providers, outletMap);
        //DO YOUR CHECK HERE
        return this.loadedComponent;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also working on RC1. Can you please tell me how to continue loading the route if check passes and how to redirect user to login page if check fails ...

Comment: @microchip78 I could not go further although it seems so it is not possible

Comment: Router outlet has changed a bit since 1.X. See here for details (methods are different that you'll need to hook).

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/index/RouterOutlet-directive.html