# How to get target url path while extending RouterOutlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working on angular rc1 and trying to extend RouterOutlet, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37790603/492258),

```
load(factory, providers, outletMap: RouterOutletMap): any {
    super.load(factory, providers, outletMap);
    let currentUrl = (<Location>location).pathname;
    if (currentUrl == "/someUrl"){
        //do something with it
    }

    return this.loadedComponent;
}
```

I can get current url, but I need to have target. How can I get it?

Comment: What router version?

Comment: Hello @GünterZöchbauer I have been following your wonderful answers:) version is : `@angular/router 2.0.0-rc.1`

Comment: I don't know. I haven't looked into overriding `RouterOutlet`. Another router is on its way already. Doesn't make much sense to investigate this deprecated router - yes `@angular/router` is also deprecated.

Comment: Is it usual such fast changes and deprecation during new product, or is this specific to angular as being it is king

Comment: That's the life of early adopters. If it turns out that a strategy leads to conflicts with your goals you have to change something.