# securing router-outlet in angular2 rc1

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am still working on Angular2 RC1 for one of my project.

I want to secure router outlet by authenticating user before loading route further. I have checked few answers on stakoverflow but none of them are complete and informative and not much documentation from Angular team as well.

[How do I extend RouterOutlet when using the new router in RC.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645771/how-do-i-extend-routeroutlet-when-using-the-new-router-in-rc-1)

but still no luck.

Comment: Well you know RC in Angular2 is 'Router Crisis'. They kept changing the `router` module and although this can easily be achieved in newer `router`  implementation, if you're still be with RC1, not many people will be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks and I can understand that but any clue or idea. Link I posted here it is bringing application to load method but from there I want to know how to continue with incoming route or reroute to login page ... thats the only issue I have currently ...